# maya python IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, maya

Who can tell me where is my error.

```
def checkMeshButton(*args):

    selectedObject=mc.ls(sl=True,tr=True)
    mc.select(selectedObject[0])
    selctedVertexNumberList=[]

    selectedVertexNumber=mc.polyEvaluate(vertex=True)
    selectedVertexNumberList.append(selectedVertexNumber)

    vertexIndexList = [v for v in range(selectedVertexNumber)]

    if dropDensity < len(vertexIndexList):
        OM.MGlobal.displayInfo("Your mesh is good to go!")
        mc.button("generateButton", edit = True, bgc=[0.15,0.4,0.15])
    else:
        OM.MGlobal.displayError("The mesh is not dense enough to make %d drops! Use the subdivide mesh function!"%dropDensity)
        mc.button("subDMeshButton", bgc=[0.15,0.4,0.15], edit=True)
```

Comment: Your indentation looks fine, you might have to check for tab at each line.

Answer (score 2):

"Ghost" indentation error often happen after a Copy/Paste from another source.
Check each line of your script to make sure that they are all indented with normal spaces and not with any other invisible characters like tabs.